# Selfdestruct in smart contract

Tags: solidity, selfdestruct

How to self-destruct a smart contract. What is the syntax of the code. Will self-destructing my smart contract will refund me any ether from the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for selfdestruct is simple: `selfdestruct(addr);`, where `addr` is the address where possible Ether balance of the contract is sent.

You will not receive a refund for the selfdestruct, since the recent London hard fork removed gas refund for selfdestruct (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3529).